# How to update Github's PAT after regeneration?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I had a perfectly working local-remote connection, but after regenerating Github's **personal access token** my project's git related commands stopped working, as expected.

When typing **git pull** for example, I was simply getting an authentication error, without opening a prompt for updating the **PAT**. Also I was unable to update **PAT** nor on macOS, nor on Windows via their credential managers.

Answer (score 3):

The [Git FAQ explains how to reset the credential manager's credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials)  (substitute `user` for your username):

```
$ echo url=https://user@github.com | git credential reject
```

This will erase the credentials from an existing credential helper, so next time you pull or push, Git will prompt you for credentials again.

Comment: Tried this option, no prompt appeared, the token was not reset.

Comment: nice, thanks, worked for me (mac ventura)